# Numpy savetxt error. ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, export-to-csv

I generated an array containing all possible combinations of 3 numbers ranging from 1 to 5 using the function `itertools.combinations()`. (But the real case will be the combination of 5 numbers from 1 to 90, but I reduced here simply to explain the case).

This gives me an array like this: `array_generated = [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]`

I tried to save this array as a csv file with the function `numpy.savetxt("file.csv",array_generated)`

Unfortunately I get an error: `ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead.`

**This is the code that presents the problem:**

```
import itertools
import numpy
numbers_range = [1,2,3,4]
array_generated = itertools.combinations(numbers_range,3)
numpy.savetxt("file.csv",array_generated)
```

**This is the error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-6ff7934c3424> in <module>()
      3 numbers_range = [1,2,3,4]
      4 array_generated = itertools.combinations(numbers_range,3)
----> 5 numpy.savetxt("file.csv",array_generated)

<__array_function__ internals> in savetxt(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1370         if X.ndim == 0 or X.ndim > 2:
   1371             raise ValueError(
-> 1372                 "Expected 1D or 2D array, got %dD array instead" % X.ndim)
   1373         elif X.ndim == 1:
   1374             # Common case -- 1d array of numbers

ValueError: Expected 1D or 2D array, got 0D array instead
```

**This is how I try to print the array to see what it contains:**

```
import itertools
import numpy
numbers_range = [1,2,3,4]
array_generated = itertools.combinations(numbers_range,3)
list(array_generated)
```

**The result printed is:** `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]`

Does anyone figure out what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at `np.array_generated)`. That's what's being saved.    A generator can only be used once.

Comment: create and save the array, not the generator.